# Exporting to Google Docs from Cognito Forms

Tags: google-sheets, cognito-forms

Is there any way to have your entries sent to a Google Spreadsheet from Cognito Forms?

Answer (score 1):

Yes! You can export your form data to your Google Drive account (and many other applications) using our [Zapier integration](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/68/data-integration/zapier). We also have a blog post that specifically explains how to update a Google Sheet whenever a new entry is submitted or updated - check it out here:

http://blog.cognitoforms.com/keep-your-form-data-in-sync-with-google-sheets